# Mysql Select by name from different table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have the following 2 tables inside MySQL:

Table Settings

```
|id |name|clientid|
------------------
| 1 | a  | 33    |
------------------
| 2 | b  | 34    |
------------------
```

Table Client

```
|id  |clientname |
------------------
| 33 | c         |
------------------
| 34 | a         |
-----------------
```

Where I am trying to make a Search query where it will always return the id from the first table.

Query so far:

```
$this->conn->prepare("SELECT Settings.id as value, 
                             Settings.name as label 
                      FROM Settings
                      LEFT JOIN client ON Settings.clientid = client.id
                      WHERE Settings.name LIKE :keyword 
                            OR Settings.id LIKE :keywordid 
                            OR client.clientname LIKE :keywordclient 
                      LIMIT 10");

$stmt->bindValue(':keyword', "%{$this->keyword}%", PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindValue(':keywordid', "%{$this->keyword}%", PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt->bindValue(':keywordclient', "%{$this->keyword}%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

So basically the idea is the following If Search for letter **a** the search will do search inside Settings to see if keywrod is LIKE id, or name, or it will have to search and see inside the client table and see if it is like Clientname. The result will always have to be the Id from Settings table and than the name or client name as label from ther other two pages depending on the result.

And in this case the results have to be two

```
value: 1 label: a
value: 2  /*from Settings table*/ label: a  /*from the client table*/
```

Any help will be appreciate solving this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to utilize [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html), by breaking the problem into two `SELECT` queries. First query would only search in the Settings table; while the second one would do the same in the Client table only. This approach has an added advantage of converting a less-efficient `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.

The SQL query will be:

```sql
(SELECT id   AS value,
        name AS label
 FROM   settings
 WHERE  name LIKE :keyword
         OR id LIKE :keyword
 LIMIT  10)
UNION
(SELECT s.id   AS value,
        c.name AS label
 FROM   settings AS s
        JOIN client AS c
          ON c.id = s.clientid
 WHERE  c.clientname LIKE :keyword
 LIMIT  10)
ORDER  BY value
LIMIT
10
```

**Note:** Since you want only 10 rows, I have put `LIMIT 10` inside both the `SELECT` queries, to optimize the data being selected for union later.

Answer (score 0):

add an order by `ORDER BY Settings.id` or `ORDER BY value` (forgot which one lol)

```
SELECT Settings.id as value,
        Settings.name as label 
    FROM Settings
        LEFT JOIN client ON Settings.clientid = client.id
    WHERE Settings.name LIKE :keyword 
        OR Settings.id LIKE :keywordid 
        OR client.clientname LIKE :keywordclient 
    ORDER BY Settings.id
    LIMIT 10
```